# Parsing mp3 as php using htaccess addhandler

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to parse mp3 files as php using this line in htaccess:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .mp3 .MP3
```

the purpose is to run an auto_prepend_file

Everything works fine. But after the auto_prepend_file is run, the server outputs the mp3 and runs with errors such as:

```
Warning: Unexpected character in input: '' (ASCII=23) state=0 i
```

Seems it is parsing the mp3 file as php. Anyway to just tell the server to treat mp3 files as php so I can use the auto_prepend_file directive and then cancelling the php handling

(I cannot use mod_rewrite for this)

The question boils down to: is there a way to cancel php parsing in mid script. so that after processing, the mp3 will just get passed thru?

Comment: Can you rename the mp3 files? I.e., having foo.mp3 renamed to foo.mp3.X and a PHP file named foo.mp3 in its place?

Comment: I also use my toaster to iron my clothes. Why would an... ah nevermind. Good look using php to parse mp3 the way you tried.

Comment: cannot rename the mp3 files

Comment: If you treat a binary file as php it will always be parsed and handled like a text file and php will throw errors for invalid chars. Why you can't use mod_rewrite?

Comment: The mp3 is binary data. You can't be sure that there is no `<?` in it

Comment: is there a way to cancel parsing after the autoprepend file is run?

Comment: You can use the [__halt_compiler()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.halt-compiler.php) function. I've never tested it together with a autoprepend file. Does it work?

Comment: got this: Fatal error: __HALT_COMPILER() can only be used from the outermost scope

Comment: can you post your autoprepend script?

Comment: see my comment under G.S.'s answer

Answer (score 1):

I'd try it like this: Use mod_rewrite to run a php script instead.

```
RewriteRule (\w+\.mp3)$ phpscript.php?file=$1
```

In this script, prepend what you want, then read the given file and output it.

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['file'];
include("prependfile.php");

header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg3');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
?>
```

Comment: Thats exactly the **same** what I've prepared :D You where a bit faster. +1 :)

Comment: thank you but need to do it as in the question. without mod_rewrite. have had all sorts of problem with headers for people streaming. tried every possible combination of "Correct headers" but no go. only time it works is if i have a direct link. this is why wanted to use auto_prepend

Comment: @RayS. You can sniff the headers from direct downloads using wireshark or whatever and doing the same with php. This will work. Btw, I've tested the `__halt_compiler()` function in an autoprepend script. It didn't work. The compiler halted only in the prepend script. In the main script php where executed again

Comment: yea good point. will have to keep trying with the headers. looks like no easy way to do this with a prepend script

Comment: You could elaborate what you want to achieve with the prepend script, maybe someone can suggest another alterntive.